# Encountering P1000 Error: Authentication Failure with Dockerized PostgreSQL Database in Prisma Migration

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, graphql, prisma

I've configured my Dockerfile with all the necessary credentials, and my Docker container is running smoothly. However, when I execute `npx prisma migrate dev --name create_user_table`, I encounter the following error:
[image: Error]

Here is my docker compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: threads-db
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" #default port of postgres:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data #store the data from this add to volume postgres data such that upon shutting off, the data is still stored in our local machine
    environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: postgres #Use this in DATABASE_URL-user in .env
       POSTGRES_DB: threads #db name
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres #do not use @ -password


volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here is my schema.prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User{
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  firstName String @map("first_name")  //at code level-firstName, in db-first_name ->mapping is not compulsory.
  lastName String @map("last_name")
  proflieImgURL String @map("profile_img_url")
  email String @unique  //will take email as it is for db
  password String
  salt String


  @@map("users")  //will make the table as users
}
```

Here is my .env-

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/threads"
```

I'm attempting to migrate the Prisma schema into a PostgreSQL database running within a Docker container. Despite verifying all the fields, I'm still encountering an error.

I'm puzzled as to where I might have gone wrong. Could anyone lend a hand in pinpointing the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!